# The second ajax request does not change the DOM after loading the first one jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, xmlhttprequest

I have two very similar jquery AJAX codes. Both work correctly when I use them separately. However, if I load the first code, if I want to load the second it probably works (because I tested different places "console.log(''test'')"), but it doesn't change the DOM. Please help.

I have tried many different solutions and none have provided a solution. I have searched on many forums but have not found an answer.

1st

```
    var basketAddTimeout;
var ajaxSubmitForm;
app_shop.run(function() {
    ajaxSubmitForm = function() {
        $this = $('#projector_button_basket');
        
        var url = $('#projector_form').attr('action');
        var txt = $this.text().trim();
        clearTimeout(basketAddTimeout);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: $('#projector_form').serializeArray(),
            success: function(data) {   
                basketAddTimeout = setTimeout(function() { 
                    
                    $('#Basket').load(' #projector-basket-form');
                }, 1000)
                fetch('/ajax/basket.php').then(res => res.json()).then(({
                    basket
                }) => {
                    const number = basket.productsNumber;
                    const number12 = basket.worth_formatted;
                    $('#kwota-basket').text(number12);
                    
                    document.getElementById('badgekoszyka').style.display = 'block';
                    $( "#badgekoszyka" ).fadeOut( "slow");
                    $( "#badgekoszyka" ).fadeIn( "slow");
                    $('#menu_basket .badge').text(number);
                    $('#badgekoszyka').text(number);    
                })
            },
            error: function() {
                classObj.alert(classObj.txt.dodano_produkt_blad);
                $('#projector_button_basket').html(txt);
                $('#projector_button_basket').removeClass('loader');
            }
      });
    }
}, 'all');
```

second

```
 var basketAddTimeout2;
var ajaxSubmitForm2;
app_shop.run(function() {
    ajaxSubmitForm2 = function() {
        var url = $('#projector-basket-form').attr('action');
        $('#loaders').addClass('loader-koszyk');
        $('#blok-koszyk').css('filter','blur(3px)');
        
        clearTimeout(basketAddTimeout2);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: $('#projector-basket-form').serializeArray(),
            success: function(data) {
                basketAddTimeout2 = setTimeout(function() {  
                        
                            
                }, 1000)
                fetch('/ajax/basket.php').then(res => res.json()).then(({
                    basket
                }) => {
                    
                    const number = basket.productsNumber;
                    const number12 = basket.worth_formatted;
                    $('#kwota-basket').text(number12);
                    $('#menu_basket .badge').text(number);
                    $('#badgekoszyka').text(number);
                    $('.topBasket').load('/basketchange.php?type=multiproduct&mode=2 .topBasket>*', function() {});
                    $('#loaders').removeClass('loader-koszyk');
                    $('#blok-koszyk').css('filter','blur(0px)');
                    document.getElementById("Basket").innerHTML = contentt;
                })
            },
            error: function() {
                classObj.alert(classObj.txt.dodano_produkt_blad);
            }
        });
    }
}, 'all')

$(document).on('click', '#usuwanie-koszyk, #dodawanie-koszyk, #usuwanie-calkowite ', function(e) {
        
    ajaxSubmitForm2();  
    e.preventDefault();
    
});
```

Comment: can you provide the source of `app_shop`? where we can see the `run` function inside of it. also, it seems like `app_shop`'s `run` function can store & execute a single function. that figures out why both individual requests are succeeding.

Comment: I've removed the shop run app from both scripts and it's still the same. This is probably related to .load () in the first script.

Answer (score 0):

You Should call `e.preventDefault()` at the priority to defend the default action on the element in the `second` request.

```
$(document).on('click', '#usuwanie-koszyk, #dodawanie-koszyk, #usuwanie-calkowite ', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    ajaxSubmitForm2()
});
```

Comment: Nope :( still nothing. CSS working but nothing more